# How logback is formatting spring boot logs, in predefined json format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

New to spring boot.

I have seen, when including the `logback-spring.xml`, it makes the spring boot to emit the logs in json format to stdout.

*logback.xml:-*

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.verizon" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />      
</logger>
```

Sample Log from console:-

```
{"created_date":"2019-01-03T15:31:47.499","log_level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"package name.classname goes here","desc":"Started SupportApplication in 60.031 seconds (JVM running for 63.974)"}
```

My questions is,

1. Which base class is having these created_date,log_level,INFO,logger,desc properties?
2. Is it possible to override the above base class to customize those properties?
3. Is logback actively listening the stdout console to capture the info "Started SupportApplication in XX seconds......"?

I tried to look around `ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender` class, but unable to find the solution to above questions.

Could some one provide inputs here.

Comment: Best way to find your answers would be to go through source code and documentation: https://logback.qos.ch/xref/index.html, https://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html

Comment: You can start with : https://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/appenders/socket/ConsolePluginClient.html